The collection is not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested
We are getting the The collection is not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested. error to frequently.
The existing code was working fine but is there any azure or Sharpoint limit with number of calls or memory thing?
If we debug the code it’s working fine but in the deployed code with more amount of data it’s not working properly.
Web web = clientContext. Web;
List list = web. Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery;
StringBuilder buildQuery = new StringBuilder);
buildQuery. Append(camlQueryXml);
camlQuery .ViewXml = Convert. ToString(buildQuery) ;
itemCollection = list. GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext. Load(list);
clientContext.Load(list.Fields);
clientContext. Load(itenCollection);
clientContext.ExecuteQueryWithIncrementalRetry; 
if (itemCollection != null)
{
    if (itemCollection.Count > 0)
    {
        return itemCollection;
    }
}

Can someone help here.

What is the exact exception being produced?  Which specific operation produces the exception?  What runtime value(s) used in that operation produce the exception?

@David we have written this common method to load the data based on the camel query and list name. It is working fine when we are debugging the code but if we deploy and based on scheduler if it’s get called then sometimes it’s working sometimes throwing the errror.

Can you edit this question to feature the actual code? It's very obvious this is just typed code, not the actual code, since there are lots of typos and syntax errors in the code present.
